# Linux server cannot start to root log in

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have the issue with Linux server which it cannot running to the log in root as below picture

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: looks like a failed hard disk

Comment: What happened before the boot? What was added/removed from the system? Why was the server rebooted? Thanks for additional information.

Answer (score 5):

Your disk is broken. Replace it and restore from backup.